# Can my WebDriver script catch a event from the webpage?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like my WebDriver script to execute some test after the webpage fires specific event. Is this possible?

In the WebDriver script there would be some kind of event listener:

```
document.addEventListener("hello", function(){
    console.log("doing tests");
});
```

That would run when the webpage would executes:

```
var ev = new Event("hello");
document.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

Is this possible the other way around, so I could fire an event from WebDriver to the webpage?

Comment: what kind of event you are taking about... can you please give some example

Comment: I edit the question. It should be clearer now...

Comment: @kaleaht - In which language are you using the webdriver?

Comment: @Jason Estibeiro JavaScript

Comment: In Selenium, there exists a thing called EventFiringWebDriver. Have never tried it, though.

Comment: EventFiringWebDriver has nothing to do with the client, it simply lets other server classes hook around WD events sent from WD instances.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it's possible to listen to an event.

This example listens to the "change" event on a file input:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://fiddle.jshell.net/lovlka/N4Jxk/show/")

driver.switch_to_frame(0)
driver.set_script_timeout(30)

# find the input
input_elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#uploadFile")

# add an event listener on an element
driver.execute_script("""\
  arguments[0].addEventListener("change", function onchange() {
    this.removeEventListener("change", onchange);
    window.__file__ = true;
  });
  window.__file__ = false;
  """, input_elem)

# upload the file
input_elem.send_keys(r"C:\text.txt")

# waits for the file
driver.execute_async_script("""\
  var callback = arguments[0];
  (function fn(){
    if(window.__file__)
      return callback();
    setTimeout(fn, 60);
  })();
  """)
```

It's also possible to generate an event.

This example simulates an HTML5 text drop:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://html5demos.com/drag-anything")

drop_element = driver.find_element_by_id("drop")
drop_format = "text/message"
drop_text = "my text"

driver.execute_script("""\
  var tgt = arguments[0], format = arguments[1], data = arguments[2],
  dataTransfer = {
    dropEffect: '',
    effectAllowed: 'all',
    files: [ ],
    items: { format: data },
    types: [ format ],
    getData: function (format) { return data; },
    clearData: function (format) { }
  };
  var emit = function (event, target) {
    var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
    evt.initEvent(event, true, false);
    evt.dataTransfer = dataTransfer;
    target.dispatchEvent(evt);
  };
  emit('dragenter', tgt);
  emit('dragover', tgt);
  emit('drop', tgt);
  """, drop_element, drop_format, drop_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old question but I just want to add some information here, maybe it was not there when this question was asked. As mentioned in question and comments that it is for Javascript implementation of webdriver , which is [`webdriverjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriverjs/v/1.7.3)

You should be able to use `addEventListener` command to add any browser supported [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)

Note, this is only supported in chrome currently

Also, this is an experimental feature in webdriver.js so  one has to add

```
var client = WebdriverJS.remote({
    logLevel: 'verbose',
    experimental: true, // <-- enables browser side eventhandling
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
});
```

And then register events like

```
client
    .url('http://google.com')
    .addEventListener('dblclick','#hplogo', function(e) {
        console.log(e.target); // -> 'id("hplogo")'
        console.log(e.type); // -> 'dblclick'
        console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY); // -> 239 524
    })
    .doubleClick('#hplogo') // triggers event
    .end();
```

You can use `removeEventListener` to unregister any registered listeners

Evenhandling in Node.js environment is also supported as implied by this

`WebdriverJS inherits several function from the NodeJS EventEmitter object`