# Selenium - watch for an error condition AND run 'happy path' test code

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

My app displays an error dialog whenever a JavaScript error occurs. This is always a bad sign, so I want to set up my tests so that, if the error dialog appears, it causes the test to fail there and then.

So I'd like to do something like (very much pseudocode!);

```
// start a new 'guard' thread;
start {
  found = this.driver.wait(untilVisible(By.css('.myErrorDialog')), VERY_LONG_TIMEOUT);
  if (found) { 
      // the error dialog appeared! That's bad!
      throw();
  }
}

// now run the test
login();
clickButton();
testBannerContains();
```

But I'm having trouble and I think it has to do with the way Selenium schedules actions.

What I've found is that for a single driver, I can only schedule one thing at a time, so the guard I set up early in the test blocks the body of the test from starting.

Is there a better way to handle conditions like 'this should never happen', or a way to create two independent threads in the same test?

Comment: Multithreading is in-built with [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running). If that is not possible then you could try something like [this](http://roadtoautomation.blogspot.in/2015/01/road-to-parallel-execution-of-selenium_11.html). [ExpectedConditions.isAlertPresent()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#alertIsPresent--) might be a better/easier/appropriate option.

Comment: Does this happen only on the initial navigation to the webpage?

Comment: @JonahOberloh no, this is at any point while a test is running. For the entire duration of the test, if an error dialog appears, the test must fail instantly

Comment: @SteveCooper Is this error dialog modal? If so then you could place your test code in a try-catch block. If the alert box pops up then the next step in code will timeout and in the catch block you can verify if it is due to the alert box. Depending if alert is present throw your custom error or if it is some other reason throw the original error.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem with the code you have is that it immediately runs it and waits for a `VERY_LONG_TIMEOUT` amount of time for that error dialog to appear. Since it never does, it continues to wait. You have already discovered that is not what you want... ;)

I haven't done anything like this but I think you want a JS event handler that watches for the event that is triggered when the error dialog appears. See the link below for some guidance there.

[Can my WebDriver script catch a event from the webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884230/can-my-webdriver-script-catch-a-event-from-the-webpage)

One option would be to watch for that event to fire and then store `true` (or whatever) in some JS variable. Before leaving a page, check to see if the variable is set to `true` and if so, fail the test. You can set and get JS variables using `JavascriptExecutor`. Some google searches should get you all you need to use it.